# Exception notification package in Python

Tags: python

In ruby, I've used the gem `exception_notification`

This will send me an email about the detailed exception information.

What's an alternative for Python?

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Do you need to get the information in an email only, or does it need to be able to community with other services?

Answer (score 2):

The standard library `logging` module. Use `logging.handlers.SMTPHandler` for email. It works in 2 and 3.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html

Comment: Seems more like a Google question though.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the standard logging library you might like to consider using  [CrashReporter](https://github.com/lobocv/crashreporter).

Example, *from the documentation*:

```
from crashreporter import CrashReporter

# Some code here that actually implements your application

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Note I have used a configuration file for setting up SMTP and FTP accounts but you can also call functions
    # cr.setup_smtp() and cr.setup_ftp() with your credentials to configure SMTP/FTP respectively.
    cr = CrashReporter(report_dir='/home/calvin/crashreporter',
                       check_interval=10,
                       config='./crashreporter.cfg')

    cr.application_name = 'My App'
    cr.application_version = '1.1.350'

    # Crash reporter set up go ahead and run your app.
```